# Category Field - Select All, or All Children

Tags: categories

Currently I am using categories to allow an entry to be filtered for the areas in which it is available. 
Therefore, as such I am by default selected most categories, and this is becoming tedious!

I have searched Devot-ee and other places, but cannot find anything that would allow for the "select all" facility on categories so that they can be deselected for the areas that are not available.

Another alternative would be to allow the functioning of the parent category being ticked, and auto selecting all of its children elements.

Can anyone advise, or think of a better alternative here? Crucially note that this is then searched on the front end, so that ability needs to remain in an efficient manner.

Thanks, N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MX Default Category](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx_default_category) - tell me if is it something what you need.

> MX Default Category ext. helps to select default categories for any
>   channels.
>
> It is also add select all trigger on parent checkbox to
>   select/deselect all child.

[image]
[image]

Comment: looks perfect thanks. it was hidden away on Github and not in Devot-ee though!!! lol. Thanks, N

Comment: It was written special for your question actually :D  I will try to find time to release it for devot-ee too.